# Extract everything until third period in stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I have this `Identifier` column

```
structure(list(Identifier = c("NC.1.OA", "NC.1.OA.0", "NC.1.OA.1", 
"NC.1.OA.1.a", "NC.1.OA.1.b", "NC.1.OA.1.c", "NC.1.OA.2", "NC.1.OA.2.0", 
"NC.1.OA.3", "NC.1.OA.4", "NC.1.OA.4.0", "NC.1.OA.9", "NC.1.OA.6", 
"NC.1.OA.6.a", "NC.1.OA.6.b", "NC.1.OA.6.c", "NC.1.OA.6.d", "NC.1.OA.6.e", 
"NC.1.OA.6.f", "NC.1.OA.6.f.0", "NC.1.OA.7", "NC.1.OA.8")), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to extract out the `NC.1.OA` from this column. Generally, that would be extracting everything from beginning to the third period, but the first row would violate that since there are only two periods.

I've tried `gsub(".*\\.(.*)\\..*", "\\1", Identifier)` with no cigar.

Comment: `sub("(\\w+[.]\\w+[.]\\w+).*", "\\1", Identifier)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = str_extract(Identifier, "NC\\.1\\.OA"))
```

---

Also, if we are using `sub` (`gsub` is not needed as we are not substituting globally), fix with a position identifier to notify the start (`^`) of the string.  In the pattern below, we match one or more characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) followed by a `.` (`[.]` - dot is a metacharacter, so we escape or place it in square brackets to evaluate literally), followed by one more digits (`\\d+`), then a `.` and characters that not a dot (as earlier), capture as a group (wrap with brackets) and in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^([^.]+[.]\\d+[.][^.]+).*", "\\1", df$Identifier)
#[1] "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA"
#[12] "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA" "NC.1.OA"
```